# Remove white space from isql output

Tags: sql, bash, isql

Is there any way to stop `isql` from adding spacing before and after the returned fields? I just want the values from the table row separated by `,`. At the moment, using `-b` and `-s ','`, I get:

```
,some_column_entry         ,          3213,            another_column_entry,
```

however, I want:

```
,some_column_entry,3212,another_column_entry,
```

I read through all the switches, but couldn't seem to find anything appropriate. My wish is to get `isql` to output in this form rather than parsing the output.

**EDIT**:

```
select top 1 rtrim(ltrim(some_column)) from table
```

returns

```
,abc             ,
```

`isql` seems to output based on the size of max characters, because if I run the following:

```
select top 1 rtrim(ltrim(convert(varchar(3), some_column)) from table
```

I get:

```
,abc,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Use RTRIM(LTRIM(ColumnName)) in your -q Query Select command.
```

Answer (score 0):

The contrast between

```
some_column_entry         ,
```

and

```
,            another_column_entry,
```

leads me to think that the spaces are part of your field entries, as opposed to the delimiters used.

From `man isql`:

> -dx    Delimit columns with x.
>
> -x0xXX Delimit columns with XX, where XX is in hex.  For example -x0x09 will use a tab.

If that doesn't work, then you can pipe the output of `isql` through a simple `sed` use case:

```
isql ... | sed -e 's/\ //g'
```

Comment: `-d` appears to be a syntax error. I would have to use `-s 'x'` to make x the column delimiter.